# linearGravityField() is not affecting physics bodies in the scene SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, game-physics, scenekit

I'm trying to use a SCNPhysicsField.linearGravityField object to affect only specific objects in my scene.  The problem is, that I can't seem to get it to affect anything.  Here's a sample of my code in Swift:

```
let downGravityCatagory = 1 << 0
let fieldDown = SCNPhysicsField.linearGravityField()
let fieldUp = SCNPhysicsField.linearGravityField()
let fieldNode = SCNNode()

let sceneView = view as! SCNView
sceneView.scene = scene
sceneView.scene!.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)

fieldDown.categoryBitMask = downGravityCatagory
fieldDown.active = true
fieldDown.strength = 3
fieldNode.physicsField = fieldDown
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(fieldNode)

var dice = SCNNode()
//I then attach geometry here
dice.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: dice.geometry!, options: nil))
dice.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = downGravityCatagory
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(dice)
```

Even though the Physics Bodies are assigned the same catagoryBitMask as the gravity field, they just float there in zero G, only affected by the physicsworld gravity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the "downGravityCatagory" bit mask on the node:

```
dice.categoryBitMask = downGravityCatagory;
```

the physics's categoryBitMask is for physics collisions only.

Comment: Yep.  That was it.  So simple.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to get my ball to fall faster. Right now it falls really slowly. I tried using this answer. I think I am close, but I do not really know. The code:

```
import Cocoa
import SceneKit

class AppController : NSObject {

@IBOutlet weak var _sceneView: SCNView!

@IBOutlet weak var _pushButton: NSButton!

@IBOutlet weak var _resetButton: NSButton!

private let _mySphereNode = SCNNode()

private let _gravityFieldNode = SCNNode()

private let downGravityCategory = 1 << 0

private func setupScene() {

    // setup ambient light source
    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    ambientLightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient
    ambientLightNode.light!.color = NSColor(white: 0.35, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    // add ambient light the scene
    _sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

    // setup onmidirectional light
    let omniLightNode = SCNNode()
    omniLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    omniLightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeOmni
    omniLightNode.light!.color = NSColor(white: 0.56, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    omniLightNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 200.0, 0.0)
    _sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(omniLightNode)

    // add plane
    let myPlane = SCNPlane(width: 125.0, height: 2000.0)
    myPlane.widthSegmentCount = 10
    myPlane.heightSegmentCount = 10
    myPlane.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = NSColor.orangeColor().CGColor
    myPlane.firstMaterial!.specular.contents = NSColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    let planeNode = SCNNode()
    planeNode.geometry = myPlane
    // rotote -90.0 degrees about the y-axis, then rotate -90.0 about the x-axis
    var rotMat = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-3.14/2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    rotMat = SCNMatrix4Rotate(rotMat, -3.14/2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    planeNode.transform = rotMat
    planeNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    // add physcis to plane
    planeNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.staticBody()
    // add plane to scene
    _sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)


    // gravity folks...
    // first, set the position for field effect
    let gravityField = SCNPhysicsField.linearGravityField()
    gravityField.categoryBitMask = downGravityCategory
    gravityField.active = true
    gravityField.strength = 3.0
    gravityField.exclusive = true
    _gravityFieldNode.physicsField = gravityField
    _sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(_gravityFieldNode)
    // attach the sphere node to the scene's root node
    _mySphereNode.categoryBitMask = downGravityCategory
    _sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(_mySphereNode)
}

private func setupBall() {

    let radius = 25.0

    // sphere geometry
    let mySphere = SCNSphere(radius: CGFloat(radius))
    mySphere.geodesic = true
    mySphere.segmentCount = 50
    mySphere.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = NSColor.purpleColor().CGColor
    mySphere.firstMaterial!.specular.contents = NSColor.whiteColor().CGColor

    // position sphere geometry, add it to node
    _mySphereNode.position = SCNVector3(0.0, CGFloat(radius), 0.0)
    _mySphereNode.geometry = mySphere

    // physics body and shape
    _mySphereNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: mySphere, options: nil))
    _mySphereNode.physicsBody!.mass = 0.125
}

private func stopBall() {

    _mySphereNode.geometry = nil
    _mySphereNode.physicsBody = nil
}

override func awakeFromNib() {

    // assign empty scene
    _sceneView.scene = SCNScene()

    setupScene()

    setupBall()
}

@IBAction func moveBall(sender: AnyObject) {

    let forceApplied = SCNVector3Make(35.0, 0.0, 0.0)

    if _mySphereNode.physicsBody?.isResting == true {

        _mySphereNode.physicsBody!.applyForce(forceApplied, impulse: true)
    }
    else if _mySphereNode.physicsBody?.isResting == false {
        print("ball not at rest...")
    }
    else {
        print("No physics associated with the node...")
    }

}

@IBAction func resetBall(sender: AnyObject) {

    // remove the ball from the sphere node
    stopBall()

    // reset the ball
    setupBall()
}
}
```

Is there some trick to get "real-world" type gravity?

Comment: I'd set the gravity to 6.  That's what I'm doing in my app, and it seems more like real life gravity.  gravityField.strength = 6.0

Comment: @tedesignz, thank you! This lead me to the more realistic results I was expecting. I set the direction vector of the field to -9.81, set the strength to a value greater than 3.0, and disabled the default world gravity. Code will be posted...

Answer (score 0):

Based on what @tedesignz suggested, here is the slightly modified working code:

```
import Cocoa
import SceneKit

class AppController : NSObject, SCNPhysicsContactDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var _sceneView: SCNView!

@IBOutlet weak var _pushButton: NSButton!

@IBOutlet weak var _resetButton: NSButton!

private let _mySphereNode = SCNNode()

private let _myPlaneNode = SCNNode()

private let _gravityFieldNode = SCNNode()

private let BallType = 1
private let PlaneType = 2
private let GravityType = 3

private func setupScene() {

    // setup ambient light source
    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    ambientLightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient
    ambientLightNode.light!.color = NSColor(white: 0.35, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    // add ambient light the scene
    _sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

    // setup onmidirectional light
    let omniLightNode = SCNNode()
    omniLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    omniLightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeOmni
    omniLightNode.light!.color = NSColor(white: 0.56, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    omniLightNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 200.0, 0.0)
    _sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(omniLightNode)

    // add plane
    let myPlane = SCNPlane(width: 125.0, height: 150.0)
    myPlane.widthSegmentCount = 10
    myPlane.heightSegmentCount = 10
    myPlane.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = NSColor.orangeColor().CGColor
    myPlane.firstMaterial!.specular.contents = NSColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    _myPlaneNode.geometry = myPlane
    // rotote -90.0 degrees about the y-axis, then rotate -90.0 about the x-axis
    var rotMat = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-3.14/2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    rotMat = SCNMatrix4Rotate(rotMat, -3.14/2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    _myPlaneNode.transform = rotMat
    _myPlaneNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

    // add physcis to plane
    _myPlaneNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Static, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: myPlane, options: nil))
    // configure physics body
    _myPlaneNode.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = BallType
    _myPlaneNode.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = BallType
    _myPlaneNode.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PlaneType


    // add plane to scene
    _sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(_myPlaneNode)
    // add sphere node
    _sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(_mySphereNode)

    // gravity folks...
    // first, set the position for field effect
    let gravityField = SCNPhysicsField.linearGravityField()
    gravityField.categoryBitMask = GravityType
    gravityField.active = true
    gravityField.direction = SCNVector3(0.0, -9.81, 0.0)
    print(gravityField.direction)
    gravityField.strength = 10.0
    gravityField.exclusive = true
    _gravityFieldNode.physicsField = gravityField
    _sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(_gravityFieldNode)

    // set the default gravity to zero vector
    _sceneView.scene!.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
}

private func setupBall() {

    let radius = 25.0

    // sphere geometry
    let mySphere = SCNSphere(radius: CGFloat(radius))
    mySphere.geodesic = true
    mySphere.segmentCount = 50
    mySphere.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = NSColor.purpleColor().CGColor
    mySphere.firstMaterial!.specular.contents = NSColor.whiteColor().CGColor

    // position sphere geometry, add it to node
    _mySphereNode.position = SCNVector3(0.0, CGFloat(radius), 0.0)
    _mySphereNode.geometry = mySphere

    // physics body and shape
    _mySphereNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: mySphere, options: nil))
    _mySphereNode.physicsBody!.mass = 0.125
    _mySphereNode.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PlaneType
    _mySphereNode.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PlaneType
    _mySphereNode.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = (BallType | GravityType)

}

private func stopBall() {

    _mySphereNode.geometry = nil
    _mySphereNode.physicsBody = nil
}

override func awakeFromNib() {

    // assign empty scene
    _sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
    // contact delegate
    _sceneView.scene!.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    setupScene()

    setupBall()
}

@IBAction func moveBall(sender: AnyObject) {

    let forceApplied = SCNVector3Make(5.0, 0.0, 0.0)

    if _mySphereNode.physicsBody?.isResting == true {

        _mySphereNode.physicsBody!.applyForce(forceApplied, impulse: true)
    }
    else if _mySphereNode.physicsBody?.isResting == false {
        print("ball not at rest...")
    }
    else {
        print("No physics associated with the node...")
    }

}

@IBAction func resetBall(sender: AnyObject) {

    // remove the ball from the sphere node
    stopBall()

    // reset the ball
    setupBall()
}


/*** SCENEKIT DELEGATE METHODS ***/
func physicsWorld(world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBeginContact contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {

    print("we have contact...")

}

func physicsWorld(world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didEndContact contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {

    print("No longer touching...")

}

}
```

Comment: **Warning**: it seems a strength value or direction vector components such that strength multiplied by direction vector produces a vector whose components are high in value can cause the SCNPhysicsContactDelegate method physicsWorld(world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didEndContact contact: SCNPhysicsContact) not to be called. manually tested it a bunch of times. I say now leave the direction vector at default of [0.0, -1.0, 0.0]...

Comment: ...and keep strength less than 100.0.